# Edit with IDLE not showing and IDLE subprocess did not make connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I have python 3.4.4. All of a sudden the option of EDIT with IDLE is not showing, even when I managed to edit the program in IDLE it shows IDLE subprocess could not make connection error. I have uninstalled and reinstalled python several times but without any success. I have also tried all the solutions in presented here but to no effect.

Comment: What solutions have you tried? Mind listing them here so others won't do again what you had failed to do.

Comment: Its happen to me before when I've locked the interpreter, usually I just log off/on or restart.

Comment: @yaobin On some other threads it involved making some changes in the regedit. <<https://superuser.com/questions/343519/python-idle-disappeared-from-the-right-click-context-menu>> However the changes listed there already exist so I didn't make any changes. Also restarting the computer did not solve the problem. For editing in IDLE I have to open t with idle.bat as EDIT with IDLE is still not coming and the subprocess error continues.

Comment: If you can possibly upgrade to 3.6 or 3.7, do so.  The 'connection error' message has been updated.  The current IDLE doc gives more reasons and fixes in https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#startup-failure.  In a terminal/console or Command Prompt, `python -m idlelib` starts IDLE.  If on Windows, you should have a clickable icon in start menu, which you can copy to desktop or pin to taskbar.  You can also use 'py' or 'py -x.y' instead of 'python'.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy  Well i upgraded to 3.7 however the problem continued to persist. In the end I just restored my laptop and removed all the apps installed. After that I reinstalled python3.4 everything is working fine, my programs are running and EDIT with IDLE is also coming